# SSH into multiple servers

Tags: java, shell, ssh

Hi I am trying to ssh into 4 servers but I am only getting in the 1st one and not the rest. if anyone can let me know where I am going wrong in this code.

```
try  {    
    File f = new File("/usr/site/html/Output.txt"); 

    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));

    out.println(f.getPath());

    String Servers[] = {"root@a1.xyz.com","root@a2.xyz.com","root@a3.xyz.com","root@a4.xyz.com"};

    for(int i =0;i<Servers.length;i++){
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh "+Servers[i]);
        output.write("\nI'm In"+Servers[i]);
        String s = "exit";
        byte[] byteS = s.getBytes();
        p.getOutputStream().write(byteS);
        output.write("\nI'm logged out ");
        output.close();
    }
```

So far I just can login into the 1st one . Any suggestions??

Thanks

Comment: You might want to try using a java ssh library instead of going to command line. Jsch works very well.

Comment: thanks Jon , I will try that out too !but it worked so far for me after moving out the output.close() outside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not solve your problem but from the first look at your codes, you close the output in the loop. Any atttemp to write to an output that is closed should give a run time error. Move `output.close()` out of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Check the exit value of the process and make sure its 0. Also, it might be a good idea to use the waitFor method of the Process object as it makes the thread waits untill the current process is terminated.

Comment: I also saw that printing the byteS gives me "java.lang.UNIXProcess@5b35249d" instead of "exit"

Comment: Your printing out the process object which is calling the tostring method and hence that output.. if you want to print byteS (doesn't take care of any encoding though..) System.out.println(new String(byteS));

Comment: also, unless you are trying to write an ssh library you would be better off using some java ssh library like http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/